# How to add row in a table on a click event of a Button

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

i want to add a row in a table on the click event of a Button.for this i am using following code. But it not work.

```
-(void)translation:(id)sender
{
    [self tableView:mainTableView numberOfRowsInSection:1];
    i+1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return i;
}
```

where i is a global variable which intialize in viewdidload function by 1;
Thanks in advance for any type of suggestion.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do it like this on button event increment an instance or global variable like you are using i so the code will look like this

```
-(void)translation:(id)sender
{
   i = i+1;
//This function will automatically call numberofrows and cellforrowatindexpath methods of tableView
   [tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return i;
}
```

Comment: thanks for help. for instance if i hhave two tables and i want to add rows on both simultaneously than how can i do it.I am doing what at the time of table creation i am assigning each one a different tag,but row create only for 2 table.

Comment: well that code will do for both just call reloadData on both tableView instances like you have tableView1 and tableView2 then on button's tap you call  [tableView1 reloadData]; [tableView2 reloadData]; but make sure both tableView's data Source should be same.Also first read some UITableViewProgramming Guide as Vince suggested

Comment: if i am distinguish tables on the basis of tag property. then how can i add row in both table.

Comment: you don't need to distinguish for adding rows

Answer (score 0):

A little suggestion : [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451), read that first.